# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.test.obm.struts.filter.OBMFilter incompatible with javax.servlet.Filter

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-7, apache-axis, websphere-8

I recently migrated my application from java6 to java7 and  Websphere 6 to 8.5. but were getting 1 error:

> [AxisServlet]: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.woden.resolver.URIResolver in Axis2 1.3 and WebSphere 8.5 by doing

When I fixed the error using the approach below:

As I am bundling axis2 engine with my application, I disabled WebSphere JAX-WS runtime. I needed to:

- configure my web moudle to PARENT LAST classloader
- set DisableIBMJAXWSEngine: true in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF of a WAR file

Now i am getting new error

> webapp E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[action]: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.test.obm.struts.filter.OBMFilter incompatible with javax.servlet.Filter

So I have tried to upgrade/degrade the javax/j2ee jar version also to solve above error javax incompatibility error but that too did not work and above error is same coming but when I am running my application by not using PARENT LAST classloader the J2EE error not coming but WSDLs are not running and getting the same:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.woden.resolver.URIResolver. again.

Comment: Please someone help suggest on this. Will be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Migrate your application to use built in WebSphere  WS runtime  (it is based on Axis2 so changes should be minimal) and remove all axis2 libs from your application.

Comment: The ClassCastException when you ran PARENT_LAST was almost certainly caused by including the Servlet API in your app.  The web container and application both have to link to the same version of that API, which means you can't bring your own.

Comment: Hi @GAS --> Migrate your application to use built in WebSphere WS runtime (it is based on Axis2 so changes should be minimal) and remove all axis2 libs from your application  --> This required code changes also OR only deleting axis2 jars from app-libs & using WebSphare WS setting is possible to do so ?

Comment: I dont know specifics of your app. I you are using proprietary Axis packages that are not available in WAS it will be required. You can use [WebSphere Migration toolkit](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/tools-WebSphere_Application_Server_Migration_Toolkit) to evaluate the migration, it might give you some hints. I'd start with the toolkit and removing libraries.

Comment: I tried removing all the axis2, axiom jars from my app-lib but still same error --> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.woden.resolver.URIResolver @Delayer & GAS or someone please help suggest what was done for u resolved this problem. Note. My app is using some axis related classes inside java codes at various places so it would not be feasible to update the java code respective to AXIS2 however removing axis2 jars don't think gonna work. How to enable the inbuilt web-service for any in the WEB-sphere ?

Comment: Hi @GAS please help suggest

Comment: please provide full stack trace of the error in your post, and also list of jars in your web-inf/lib

Comment: HI @GAS --> Error is --> [7/18/18 4:09:45:241 GMT] 000000d2 SystemOut     O connection obj ==com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection@69510a76
[7/18/18 4:09:45:247 GMT] 000000d2 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service Uncaught service() exception thrown by servlet action: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.woden.resolver.URIResolver

Comment: allback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
 at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
 at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
 at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
 at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
 at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
 at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.woden.resolver.URIResolver

Comment: & The jars listed in my libs are --> struts.jar               
axiom-api.jar               
axiom-dom.jar               
axiom-impl.jar              
axis2-adb-codegen.jar , axis2-adb.jar               
axis2-ant-plugin.jar        
axis2-clustering.jar        
axis2-codegen.jar           
axis2-corba.jar             
axis2-fastinfoset.jar       
axis2-java2wsdl.jar         
axis2-jaxbri.jar            
axis2-jaxws-api.jar

Comment: axis2-jaxws.jar             
axis2-jibx.jar              
axis2-json.jar              
axis2-jws-api.jar           
axis2-kernel.jar            
axis2-metadata.jar          
axis2-mtompolicy.jar        
axis2-spring.jar            
axis2-xmlbeans.jar

Comment: Woden API jar is already there & tried all the solution like disabling the WEB-service in web-sphere.. parent class loader first.. removing all axis jars from libs.. but seems nothing working out for this error and is same yet. :(

Comment: You better edit your original post rather that add comments as it is barely readable. Are these all of your jars from WEB-INF/lib? Where do you have that woden packages?

Comment: Hi @GAS , Yes all the jars from /ext-jars/ . Woden packages under /ext-jars/

Comment: What do you mean by ext-jars? Where this is located?

Comment: this a shared-libs or jars path /test/ext-jars/ outside the ears on the server I created to point here to all jars through WebSphere as RND purpose until this issue is not resolved to save time of multiple deployments.

Comment: @GAS now again I tried loading parent last first classloader and getting a new exception --> Error 500: java.lang.LinkageError: loading constraint violation when resolving method "org/apache/axis2/client/FaultMapKey.<init>(Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;Ljava/lang/String;)V" : loader "com/ibm/ws/classloader/CompoundClassLoader@6218a49" of class "com/test/testgcgi/wsdls/common/testgeneric/v5_23_0_0/testGenericServiceStub" and loader "org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader@936b0f0c" of class "org/apache/axis2/client/FaultMapKey" have different types for the method signature

Comment: These /test/ext-jars, are they in the defined Shared Library or you attaching it to classpath in some other way? Looks like you have conflicting xml libraries there... You may try to define it as 'isolated' shared library, and then reference to the application during application installation.

Comment: H @GAS /test/ext-jars is inside deployed EAR only and pointing the complete deployed path to /test/ext-jars/  under shared-libs/class-path under WAS. 2-> I tried the options you suggested for isolated class load under shared-lib & this did not work but error is same coming as above. Please help.

Comment: if you define it as shared library, the jars must be outside of the ear, on the file system. Do not include the jars in ear if you are defining it as shared lib in WAS.

Comment: @Gas I have resolved the problems. I had to add several axis2 jars & update few. Thanks.

Comment: @GAS However app is error free only by having the shared-libs outside of ears. When trying to have the jars inside ears, it is throwing the errors which I am trying to resolve as the jars must be kept inside ears & pointed accordingly.